# So I made this social media thingy for my friends I soon get this error when deploying it to heroku (problem with Gunicorn?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku

2020-10-29T16:55:30.819011+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-10-29 16:55:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4

2020-10-29T16:55:30.819587+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-10-29 16:55:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:6405 (4)

2020-10-29T16:55:30.819668+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-10-29 16:55:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync

2020-10-29T16:55:30.824820+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-10-29 16:55:30 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830204+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-10-29 16:55:30 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830206+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830223+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830224+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830225+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830225+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830225+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830226+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830226+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830227+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830227+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830227+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830228+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830228+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830229+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830229+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod = importlib.import_module(module)

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830229+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830230+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830230+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830231+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 983, in _find_and_load

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830231+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830232+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830232+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830233+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 983, in _find_and_load

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830233+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830234+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Django-Twitter-Clone'

2020-10-29T16:55:30.830309+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-10-29 16:55:30 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)

2020-10-29T16:55:30.869709+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-10-29 16:55:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master

2020-10-29T16:55:30.869972+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-10-29 16:55:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

What could be causing this error? am I overlooking this??? Please help lol

Comment: btw im using djando framework idk if that changes anything but yeah

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question is missing so many things. Show your `Procfile`, `requirements.txt`

Comment: I had fixed this issue. took me about 3 days ahah

Comment: @astrctly then you can post the answer here so it will help others https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Hey, i have the issue,  would you share your solution as well please ?